# PHP Array Search Return Multiple Keys

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.5

I'm trying to search an array and return multiple keys

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"1","b"=>"2","c"=>"2");
echo array_search("2",$a);
?>
```

With the code above it only returns b, how can I get I to return b and c?

Comment: use array_keys function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it says in the manual for [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

> To return the keys for all matching values, use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional **search_value** parameter instead.

---

#### Example:

```
$a=array("a"=>"1","b"=>"2","c"=>"2");
print_r(array_keys($a, "2"));
```

#### Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => c
)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to display the output as just b,c or b c?

Answer (score 3):

I am adding this in case someone finds it helpful. If you're doing with multi-dimensional arrays.
Suppose you have this

```
        $a = array(['user_id' => 2, 'email_id' => 1], ['user_id' => 2, 'email_id' => 2, ['user_id' => 3, 'email_id' => 1]]);
```

You want to find `email_id` of `user_id` 2.
You can do this

```
        print_r(array_keys(array_column($a, 'user_id'), 2));
```

This will return `[0,1]`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use array_keys instead:

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"1","b"=>"2","c"=>"2");
echo array_keys(array($a, "2");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers taxicala but what I was looking for is something that allows me to find all instances of the word im searching for not just the first instance.

Comment: it's what array_keys does